# Insert 2 dates into ssms. 1st and second date generated by default seperated by dash

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

What I want is to have a date_open column where there are two dates separted by a dash. I want both dates generated by default for example(todays date - 1 month from now). Which type of data do i pick? datetime I thought was meant for only 1 date. What type of formula would this be? Something like datetime() + 1?

Comment: You would use two columns for that.

Comment: Is there no way to use one column?

Comment: You can use a string column, but not advised

Comment: What is your reasoning for wanting to use a single column?

Comment: Not only would using a string column not be advised, it is strongly advised against. It would make whatever you are doing a huge pain, if not now, eventually. Doubly so for the future maintainers of whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: Just one less column but it's fine if I need to use two. What would the second dates function be? Colmun1 + 1?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses a computed column. Note, it still has the original two, and also a third based on the two.

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (D1 DATE, 
                    D2 DATE, 
                    Comb AS CONVERT(VARCHAR,D1) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,D2))
INSERT INTO @Tab 
VALUES (GETDATE(),DATEADD(MM,1,GETDATE()))
SELECT *
FROM @Tab
```

EDIT:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (D1 DATE,
                    Comb AS CONVERT(VARCHAR,D1) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(MM,1,D1)))
INSERT @Tab 
VALUES (GETDATE())
SELECT *
FROM @Tab
```

Comment: What about a second just based on the first?

Comment: @okaSKR , sure.